# Modifying Code of Function at Runtime

Tags: python

I am trying to write a decorator that adds verbose logging to a function via a decorator (a method would be nice too, but I haven't tried that yet). The motivation behind this is that patching in a one-line add_logs decorator call into a box in production is much easier (and safer) than adding 100 debug lines.

Ex:

```
def hey(name):
    print("Hi " + name)
    t = 1 + 1

    if t > 6:
        t = t + 1
        print("I was bigger")
    else:
        print("I was not.")
    print("t = ", t)
    return t
```

I'd like to make a decorator that will transform this into code that does this:

```
def hey(name):
    print("line 1")
    print("Hi " + name)

    print("line 2") 
    t = 1 + 1

    print("line 3")
    if t > 6:
        print("line 4")
        t = t + 1
        print("line 5")
        print("I was bigger")
    else:
        print("line 6")
        print("I was not.")
   print("line 7") 
   print("t = ", t)
   print("line 8")
   return t
```

What I've got so far:

```
import inspect, ast
import itertools
import imp

def log_maker():
     line_num = 1
    while True:
        yield ast.parse('print("line {line_num}")'.format(line_num=line_num)).body[0]
        line_num = line_num + 1

def add_logs(function):
    def dummy_function(*args, **kwargs):
        pass
    lines = inspect.getsourcelines(function)
    code = "".join(lines[0][1:])
    ast_tree = ast.parse(code)
    body = ast_tree.body[0].body

    #I realize this doesn't do exactly what I want.
    #(It doesn't add debug lines inside the if statement)
    #Once I get it almost working, I will rewrite this
    #to use something like node visitors
    body = list(itertools.chain(*zip(log_maker(), body)))
    ast_tree.body[0].body = body
    fix_line_nums(ast_tree)
    code = compile(ast_tree,"<string>", mode='exec')

    dummy_function.__code__ = code
    return dummy_function

def fix_line_nums(node):
    if hasattr(node, "body"):
        for index, child in enumerate(node.body):
            if hasattr(child, "lineno"):
                if index == 0:
                    if hasattr(node, "lineno"):
                        child.lineno = node.lineno + 1
                    else:
                        # Hopefully this only happens if the parent is a module...
                        child.lineno = 1
                else:
                    child.lineno = node.body[index - 1].lineno + 1
            fix_line_nums(child)

@add_logs
def hey(name):
    print("Hi " + name)
    t = 1 + 1

    if t > 6:
        t = t + 1
        print("I was bigger")
    else:
        print("I was not.")
    print("t = ", t)
    return t

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(hey("mark"))
    print(hey)
```

This produces this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so.py", line 76, in <module>
    print(hey("mark"))
TypeError: <module>() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

which makes sense because compile creates a module and of course modules are not callables. I've tried a hundred different ways of making this work at this point but can't come up with a working solution. Any recommendations? Am I going about this the wrong way?

(I haven't been able to find a tutorial for the ast module that actually modifies code at runtime like this. A pointer to such a tutorial would be helpful as well)

Note: I am presently testing this on CPython 3.2, but a 2.6/3.3_and_up solution would be appreciated. Currently the behavior is the same on 2.7 and 3.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you compile the source, you get a code object representing a module, not a function.  Substituting this code object into an existing function won't work, because it's not a function code object, it's a module code object.  It's still a code object, though, not a real module, you so can't just do `hey.hey` to get the function from it.

Instead, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19850143/how-to-compile-a-string-of-python-code-into-a-module-whose-functions-can-be-call), you need to use `exec` to execute the module's code, store the resulting objects in a dictionary, and extract the one you want.  What you could do, roughly, is:

```
code = compile(ast_tree,"<string>", mode='exec')
mod = {}
exec(code, mod)
```

Now `mod['hey']` is the modified function.  You could reassign the global `hey` to this, or replace its code object.

I am not sure if what you're doing with the AST is exactly right, but you will need to do the above at any rate, and if there are problems in the AST manipulation, doing this will get you to a point where you can start to debug them.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. (And my AST manipulations appear to be working correctly as we;;. : ) )

Comment: @marky1991: Incidentally, you might want to look at [`sys.settrace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.settrace) and/or the [`trace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/trace.html) module.  These might allow you to get the trace output you want in a less cumbersome way.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're trying to hackily implement a trace function.  Can I suggest using `sys.settrace` to accomplish that in a more reusable fashion?

```
import sys

def trace(f):
    _counter = [0] #in py3, we can use `nonlocal`, but this is compatible with py2
    def _tracer(frame, event, arg):
        if event == 'line':
            _counter[0] += 1
            print('line {}'.format(_counter[0]))
        elif event == 'return': #we're done here, reset the counter
            _counter[0] = 0
        return _tracer
    def _inner(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            sys.settrace(_tracer)
            f(*args, **kwargs)
        finally: 
            sys.settrace(None)
    return _inner

@trace
def hey(name):
    print("Hi " + name)
    t = 1 + 1

    if t > 6:
        t = t + 1
        print("I was bigger")
    else:
        print("I was not.")
    print("t = ", t)
    return t

hey('bob')
```

Output:

```
$ python3 test.py
line 1
Hi bob
line 2
line 3
line 4
I was not.
line 5
t =  2
line 6
```

Note that the semantics of this are slightly different than in your implementation; the `if` branches not exercised by your code, for example, are not counted.

This ends up being less fragile - you're not actually modifying the code of the functions you're decorating - and has extra utility.  The trace function gives you access to the frame object before executing each line of code, so you're free to log locals/globals (or do some dodgy injection stuff, if you're so inclined).

Answer (score 1):

When you call `inspect.getsource()` with a decorated function, you also get the decorator, which, in your case, gets called recursively (just twice, and the second time it produces an `OSError`).

You can use this workaround to remove `@add_logs` line from the source:

```
lines = inspect.getsourcelines(function)
code = "".join(lines[0][1:])
```

**EDIT:**

It looks like your problem is that your dummy_function doesn't take arguments:

```
>>> print(dummy_function.__code__.co_argcount)
0
>>> print(dummy_function.__code__.co_varnames)
()
```

Whereas your original function does:

```
>>> print(hey.__code__.co_argcount)
1
>>> print(hey.__code__.co_varnames)
('name')
```

**EDIT:**

You're right about the `code` object being returned as a module. As pointed in another answer, you have to execute the this object and then, assign the resulting function (identifiable by `function.__name__`) to `dummy_function`.

Like so:

```
code = compile(ast_tree,"<string>", mode='exec')
mod = {}
exec(code, mod)
dummy_function = mod[function.__name__]
return dummy_function
```

Then:

```
>>> print(hey('you'))
line 1
Hi you
line 2
line 3
I was not.
line 4
t =  2
line 5
2
```

Comment: This is true and is a valid bug, but even if I parse the original source correctly my approach is still flawed in that it's trying to call a module as if it were a function, which I still don't know how to avoid. Thanks for this correction though. (Post this fix, I still get my original error, of course)

Comment: @marky1991 I know that you still get the error, because I still have it too :) Have a look at `function.__code__.co_varnames` and `dummy_function.__code__.co_varnames` and you'll notice that your dummy function is valid but does not take any argument.

Comment: @marky1991 also, it's often better not to edit your question with answer's remarks because then answers don't mean anything anymore to an external reader

Comment: Sorry. I see that my dummy_function doesn't take any arguments and has no local variables. Isn't that because it's actually a module?